# Ubuntu 12.04 - confirm unmet dependencies

Tags: linux, oracle, ubuntu, apt-get

I want to install Oracle XE 10g AND Shorewall on Ubuntu 12.04

Problem:
Oracle XE 10g needs "bc:i386" and Shorewall needs "bc" (both are dependencies....)

I think it is not possible to have both bcs......
As Oracle XE 10g only needs "bc:386" for configure (and not for running the database after configure) - the idea is following:

1. install Oracle XE 10g with "bc:386"
2. deinstall "bc:i386" (database still runs - bc:i386 was only needed for configure) with command: "dpkg -r --force-depends bc:i386"
3. install shorewall (and "bc") and everyone is happy.

**problem:**
when I want to use apt-get after "dpkg -r --force-depends bc:i386" it is complaining about unmet dependencies.

```
apt-get install shorewall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 oracle-xe-universal:i386 : Depends: bc:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 shorewall : Depends: bc but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I solve this problem?
And please remember - I want to use Oracle XE 10g AND shorewall - so please no answers like "use mysql instead of oracle" and so on ;-)

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem seemed to be handled [in this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96282/conflict-between-amd64-and-i386-packages-with-same-dependencies)

My first advice is as in that post: install the amd64 variant *bc* and ignore the *bc:i386* package.

Also it is not clear to me if you tried the suggested solution `apt-get -f -install` and if so what happened.

In general it is no good great help to mix up *dpkg* and *apt-get* for manipulating the package database except you know exactly what you do.

Another variant you could try is to specify oracle and shorewall in one apt-get install call and go through all the resolver suggestions. (Take care: this can be a time consuming hard way to go, especially with the option *--full-resolver* enabled)

Comment: hi and thank you for your answer.

ad1) why using 32bit-version??
I'm forced to use 32bits due to the fact there is no 64bit linux version for oracle xe. I need bc i386 as a dependency.....
As in your link - this does not solve my problem :-/

Comment: ad2) why don't do a "apt-get -f install"
If you do this, than oracle XE will be removed.... this is exactly my problem ;-)

> apt-get -f install
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> Correcting dependencies... Done
> The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
>   libreadline6:i386
> Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>   oracle-xe-universal:i386
> The following held packages will be changed:
>   oracle-xe-universal:i386
> After this...ill be freed.

Comment: Just for your information - I could not solve it. So I used ufw instead of shorewall....(what caused other problems with ufw and openvz -> so I only used iptables......)